# Unable to install R >3.6 version

Tags: software-installation, r

I am trying to install R >3.6 version on my system, but every time it is giving this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.3-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include (a) your Ubuntu version information and (b) any PPAs that you added in order to install R